# Static linking sqlcipher

Tags: c++, sqlite, static-linking, sqlcipher, odb

I'm having problems with static linking, which is not the dynamic.

13 step my `Dockerfile` (see below) when configuring I get the following:

```
 ...
 checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
 configure: error: Library crypto not found. Install openssl!"
```

Dockerfile

```
 #STEP 4: Set OpenSSL version
 ENV OPENSSL_VERSION 1.0.2d

 #STEP 5: Download and install no-shared OpenSSL 
 RUN wget "http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz" && \
     tar xf openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz && \
     cd openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION && \
     export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC" && \
     export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC" &&\
     CC="gcc -fPIC" ./config no-shared \
                        --prefix=/usr \
                        --libdir=lib && \
     make && \
     make install && \
       cd ..

 #STEP 12: Download sqlcipher
 RUN git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.git

 #STEP 13: Install no-shared sqlcipher
 RUN cd sqlcipher && \ 
     ./configure  --disable-tcl --disable-shared --enable-tempstore=yes \
     CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" LDFLAGS="/usr/lib/libcrypto.a" && \
     make && \
     make install && \
     cd ..
```

Comment: Full Dockerfile see in https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/132

Comment: Dockerfile for dynamic link see in https://gist.github.com/designerror/5880201a1f20aabbb81b